# Как настроить проект?

Tags: c++, c

Мне нужна помощь в настройке проекта, который я нашел на github (https://github.com/butor/blackbird).

Я новичок в программировании и до этого не делал ничего больше, чем небольшие приложения связанные с геометрией, но не об этом, я просто даже не знаю как запустить этого бота, просто для меня такой "интерфейс" в новинку. Как открыть этого бота для взаимодействий и дебага?

Comment: Вопрос не глупый, но слишком глобальный (общий). Постарайтесь выделить более мелкие части и решать их постепенно, задавая частные вопросы по мере необходимости.

Comment: @alexolut Хорошо, тогда вопрос первый - Допустим, что конфиг настроен, и тогда как запустить его (я так понимаю, он будет в консоли)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Любой "вменяемый" проект содержит инструкцию по сборке. Как правило, эта инструкция содержится либо в файле INSTALL.md, либо (как в данном случае) в файле README.md. Конкретно, в этом файле данного проекта есть инструкции по установке дя Ubuntu, Docker и Mac OS X. Например, для Ubuntu:

1. Run the following commands:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libssl-dev libjansson-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libsqlite3-dev sendemail make gcc g++
   mkdir blackbird
   cd blackbird
   git clone --recursive  git://github.com/butor/blackbird.git .
   cmake -B./build -H. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
   cmake --build ./build -- install
   ```
2. Run the software, by typing:

   ```
   ./blackbird
   ```

Что конкретно здесь непонятно? Или Вы уже собрали проект и пытаетесь настроить работу этого приложения?

**Покомандный комментарий**

Первая команда:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev libjansson-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libsqlite3-dev sendemail make gcc g++
```

Здесь устанавливаются программные средства, необходимые для сборки программы:

- Файлы заголовков для библиотеки ssl
- Файлы заголовков для библиотеки janson
- Файлы заголовков для библиотеки curl4-openssl
- Файлы заголовков для библиотеки sqlite3
- Программа sendemail (не понимаю - зачем?!)
- Программа gcc - компилятор языка С
- Программа g++ - компилятор языка С++

  mkdir blackbird

Создаём каталог blackbird в котором будем собирать программу

```
cd blackbird
```

Переходим в только что созданный каталог

```
git clone --recursive  git://github.com/butor/blackbird.git .
```

Забираем из git-репозитария всё необходимое для сборки программы. Сама программа git должна у Вас быть установлена.

```
cmake -B./build -H. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

Выполняем сборку программы с помощью утилиты cmake. Она тоже должна быть установлена.

```
cmake --build ./build -- install
```

Выполняем установку собранной программы.
Подчеркну, что **все** программы, которые Вам нужно установить - это свободное ПО и они имеются в варианте дляя виндовоза.

Comment: Да я видел, но я первый раз такой проект собираю и честно не понимаю как использовать эту инструкцию, поэтому и задал вопрос.

Comment: У меня windows.

Comment: **не понимаю как использовать эту инструкцию** - эту инструкцию - никак. Она ориентирована на люних. Но положение не безнадёжно. Тут использованы только самые простые команды. Я подредактировал свой ответ, что бы Вы могли самостоятельно решить, что Вам надо делать в винде.

Comment: Я все установил, скачал библиотеки, только я не знаю как их использовать и CMake до этого не работал, можете написать, как именно собрать программу с помощью CMake и что делать с библиотеками (ssl. janson ...)

Comment: **можете написать, как именно собрать программу с помощью CMake** - если в двух словах, то cmake открывает файл (по умолчанию) CMakeLists.txt и читает из него инструкцию по сборке проекта. Я даже не буду пытаться перечислять тут все возможные команды cmake, просто рекомендую глянуть книжку Д. В. ДУБРОВ, "СИСТЕМА ПОСТРОЕНИЯ ПРОЕКТОВ CMAKE". Она есть в иНете. В этом файле должно выполняться подключение библиотек, компиляция и сборка. Так что, теоретически, вы должны только ввести те 2 строки, которые написаны в инструкции.

Comment: Я все сделал, запустил CMake, сгенерировать
 проект. У меня в диалоговом окне только `CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.`, и перечисляет библиотеки. Как мне их установить, чтобы он их находил?

Comment: **Как мне их установить, чтобы он их находил? ** - Как это сделать в люнихе - я знаю. А про виндовоз ничего не скажу, не знаю.